# Will using the Linux Kernel support current programs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

There are many distributions of Linux. All of them have one thing in common, however: the kernel. And Linux programs run across all of them. If I make a minimalistic distribution from the kernel, will current programs made for Linux run? What defines the differences of distributions? I am a beginner on this stuff, don't go harsh if it is a stupid question. Thank you

Comment: Depending on how you design your code, it can be compilable and work fine in most architectures and even across operational systems. If a binary will work across platforms, now that is a different story. As far as I know, if your application don't have dependencies on libraries that are not part of the standard, it should run fine in any version of Linux, as long as you are on the same architecture (say, X86 for instance) but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with caveats.

You need to make sure you have full C support and by that I mean something like glibc installed or installable or you cannot build programs for your minimal install. If you can install and compile C programs on Linux then you can in effect build practically everything else from scratch.

If you want to be able to download binaries and run them this is different, the binaries will likely require shared libraries that they would have on the systems they were built for. Unless you have those libraries you cannot run the existing binaries you find online.

> What defines the differences of distributions?

There are a lot of defining factors in each distribution. If we disregard things like...

1. Licensing ie Redhat vs Debian
2. Stance on things like GPL/BSD/NonFree
3. Release schedules Debian Vs Ubuntu
4. Target audience ie Ubuntu vs Debian

I think the biggest defining factor is package management ie yum/rpm vs apt/dpkg and how the base configuration is managed on the machine. This is certainly the thing I seem to use the most and miss the most when I change distributions. The kernel itself is very rarely on my mind which is in part a large part of it's success.

Most people start with something like ISO Linux and get a bootable CD but even then you normally choose a base distribution. If you want to create a base distributions that's a ton of work. Have a look at this great info graphic of the linux family tree

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#/media/File:Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg

If you look at Debian/Ubuntu the amount of infrastructure these distributions have setup is quite staggering. They have millions perhaps even billions of lines of code in them all designed to run on their supported versions. You might be able to take a binary from one of them and run it on Redhat but it's likely to fail unless the planets are in alignment etc. Some people think this is actually a bad thing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingo_Moln%C3%A1r#Quotes

> The basic failure of the free Linux desktop is that it's, perversely, not free 
>   enough...
>
> > Desktop Linux distributions are trying to "own" 20 thousand
> >     application packages consisting of over a billion lines of code and have 
> >     created parallel, mostly closed ecosystems around them... The Linux package 
> >     management method system works reasonably well in the enterprise (which is a
> >     hierarchical, centrally planned organization in most cases), but desktop Linux 
> >     on the other hand stopped scaling 10 years ago, at the 1000 packages limit...

Answer (score 0):

> If I make a minimalistic distribution from the kernel, will current programs made for Linux run?

Very few programs actually use the kernel directly. They also need a libc, which is responsible for actually implementing most of the C routines used by either the programs themselves or the VMs running their code.

It is possible to statically link the libc to the program, but this both bloats the size of the program and makes it impossible to fix security issues in the linked libraries without rebuilding the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, certain programs demand a specific version of the kernel. Usually these programs act as "drivers" for the rest of the system (e.g. nvidia proprietary drivers: some of them act in kernel space while others run in user space, but require that very specific kernel module and thus that very specific kernel build).

A less stricter case is when a program demand a specific capability from kernel. For example almost all modern Linux virtualization systems rely on [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) feature. Thus, to use them you need to have a reasonably fresh kernel.

Nevertheless a lot of kernel API is stable, so you can rely on it. But usually programs don't call kernel routines directly. A typical way to use a kernel function is to call a correspondent library routine which wraps and leverages the kernel API. The main, most basic library of that kind is `libc`.

Technically programs compiled for one version of `libc` (as well as other shared libraries) can be used with slightly different versions of correspondent libraries. For example, a lot of people  use Skype compiled for SuSE in completely different Linux distributions. That Skype is a pretty complex application with a lot libraries being linked in and so on, but nevertheless it works without any significant problem. So that with a lot of other proprietary programs, which couldn't be compiled for a given distribution or even for a given installation. But sometimes shit just happens :) Those binary incompabilities are quite rare but they happen from time to time.